# Dynamodb design recommendations for partial comparisons

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema, dynamodb-queries, database-indexes

I currently have a Dynamodb table with the following columns - Id (Partition Key), NativeTimestampAndPath (Range Key), EntryTimestamp (Attribute). No secondary indexes as of now.

**Sample data looks like this:**

```
Id (Partition Key)         |     NativeTimestampAndPath (Range Key)                             |     EntryTimestamp
event1#type1#eventid1      |     1960-01-01T00:00:00Z#event/event_name=event_1/event_type=type=1/day=15/eventid1-file1.json    |   2012-01-15T00:00:00Z  
event1#type1#eventid1      |     1970-01-01T00:00:00Z#event/event_name=event_1/event_type=type=1/day=16/eventid1-file2.json    |   2012-01-16T00:00:00Z  
event2#type1#eventid2      |     1970-01-01T00:00:00Z#event/event_name=event_2/event_type=type=1/day=17/eventid2-file1.json    |   2012-01-17T00:00:00Z  
event2#type1#eventid2      |     2000-01-01T00:00:00Z#event/event_name=event_2/event_type=type=1/day=18/eventid2-file2.json    |   2012-01-18T00:00:00Z
```

**Required access patterns:**

1. Conditional insert into table if `NativeTimestampAndPath` value does not already exist in the table for a given `Id`.
2. Search for all `NativeTimestampAndPath` values for a given `Id`.
3. Search for all `NativeTimestampAndPath` values for a given `Id` that are `equal/greater than/greater than or equal/less/less than or equal` to a given timestamp. For example, if my given timestamp is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` and the condition is to find all `NativeTimestampAndPath` containing timestamps less or equal to the given timestamps, the search query should return only the first 3 rows from the above table.
4. Search for all `NativeTimestampAndPath` values for a given `Id` and only return 1 `NativeTimestampAndPath` value that contains the max/min timestamp of all.

In summary, patterns 3 and 4 require a comparison on just the timestamp part of `NativeTimestampAndPath` column values.

While implementing this comparison logic, I noticed that I got inaccurate results for `equal/greater than/greater than or equal/less/less than or equal` conditions because Dynamodb is comparing the given timestamp with the entire value (timestamp and path included) in the `NativeTimestampAndPath` column. Inaccurate results are as a result of lexical comparison instead of timestamp to timestamp comparison.

**Code for the comparison logic:**

```java
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Event> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Event> ();
queryExpression
        .withHashKeyValues (event)
        .withConsistentRead (false);
queryExpression.setLimit (500);
FilterType.Conditional operator = filterDto.getTimestampOperator (); // comparison condition string
Instant                givenTimestamp  = filterDto.getTimestamp (); // given timestamp
if (operator != null && givenTimestamp != null) {
    Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition ();
    switch (operator) {
        case eq:
            rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator (ComparisonOperator.BEGINS_WITH);
            break;
        case gt:
            rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator (ComparisonOperator.GT);
            break;
        case ge:
            rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator (ComparisonOperator.GE);
            break;
        case lt:
            rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator (ComparisonOperator.LT);
            break;
        case le:
            rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator (ComparisonOperator.LE.toString ());
            break;
    }
    rangeKeyCondition.withAttributeValueList (new AttributeValue ().withS (String.valueOf (givenTimestamp)));
    queryExpression.withRangeKeyCondition ("NativeTimestampAndPath", rangeKeyCondition);
}
FilterType.Aggregate aggregate = filterDto.getTimestampAggregator (); //specifies if max or min is required
if (aggregate != null) {
    queryExpression.setLimit (1);
    switch (aggregate) {
        case max:
            queryExpression.setScanIndexForward (false);
            break;
        case min:
            queryExpression.setScanIndexForward (true);
            break;
    }
}
QueryResultPage<Event> paginated;
List<Event>            result = new ArrayList<> ();
do {
    paginated = dbMapper.queryPage (Event.class, queryExpression);
    result.addAll (paginated.getResults ());
    queryExpression.setExclusiveStartKey (paginated.getLastEvaluatedKey ());
} while (paginated.getLastEvaluatedKey () != null && aggregate == null);
return result;
```

**Assuming that I want to:**

- Keep the `Id` as the partition key and the `NativeTimestampAndPath` as the range key
- And only use query expressions (vs scan expressions) for access patterns 3 and 4

What can I do to this Dynamodb design to meet the required access pattern conditions? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right, the sort key is going to be treated as a string. Is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z#event/event_name=event_1/event_type=type=1/day=16/eventid1-file2.json` less than or equal to `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`? No, it's slightly later in a lexical sort. It will be impossible to directly include any equality expectations here if you have extra data after the timestamp.

Here's the trick. Is that long string less than `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z$`? Yes! Because $ is a character above # in ASCII. Therefore, less than this value with the dollar sign would actually count as less than or equal. You can use ! for the other direction.

I'm not sure what your issue is with #4. You can specify a `Limit` and control direction with `ScanIndexForward`. Ties where the timestamps are the same will be kind of randomly chosen, but that's unrelated to the data model here.